# Keyboard and Trackpad are not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

Bought used MacBook Pro 2018 touch-bar. The previous owner already made a factory reset.

Now, I'm trying to make the first setup of Macbook, but the keyboard and trackpad are not working (even I can't go to safe mode). I'm not able to select a country in the setup window.

I can't go to apple service, cause in the country where I'm living, there's no apple service. And can't give back to the previous owner, cause I'm not in the US.

[image]

Comment: Can you try to use an external keyboard & mouse?  You use those to get into safe mode.

Comment: Could finished setup with external keyboard and mouse. But still keyboard and trackpad don’t work.

Comment: using the External keyboard, reset SMC https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252125/313842 Answer by Monomeeth.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310819/macbook-pro-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working-all-solutions-found-have-failed?rq=1 has some tips in the Q itself too.

Comment: Tried solutions of the first link, not helped. Replacing of the top case assembly is not solution for me. As I said before, in the place where I’m living there’s no apple service. No idea what to do.